Trilogy that had a Damascus-steel sword
A more powerful and technologically advanced culture (that I seem to remember was coded roman) invades other countries with a set of rules. If they do not have total/majority control of the country after one year of fighting, then they will retreat for a period of... ten years?
Parts of the story talk about a god and his actions but the narrative reveals that's is just a guy and his friends doing things and pretending to be the god?
An upper class girl is taken or hides as a slave or servant and then winds up with a different culture in the same country. This culture lives in the desert, only does stuff at night, and has an eye mutation which allows them to see better at night.
It's a trilogy.
I read it in 2014, so it's older than that.
The enemy had stronger swords with a 'wave pattern,' and I assumed was Damascus.
Enemy tattoos people with a code.
There was city that had one visible entrance, and an entrance via a river which they used to get supplies during a siege.

Vague resemblance to Wilbur Smiths "Taita"/Ancient Egypt" series. IIRC a new metal sword (iron) vs the Egyptian bronze, desert (Egypt) and invading Hyksos(?) cause the Egyptians to retreat somewhere up the Nile, perhaps to Ethiopia?

Vague hints of "Enlibar steel" from Thieves' World across a variety of stories in the first few anthologies.

This I believe is Hilari Bell's series The Farsala Trilogy, The first volume Flame was published in 2003 (and was later retitled Fall of a Kingdom).
Here are a couple of quotes:

The commander smiled. “This is the advantage of good intelligence, my friends. The Hrum try not to let it be known among the lands in their path, but their commanders are given a time limit—one year from the day of the first battle. If at the end of that year they do not control all cities, large towns, and most of the countryside, their army is withdrawn, and negotiations begin for the country they attacked to become an independent, allied state.”

and

The traders even say that the Hrum have swords made of steel that is far stronger than ours.”

The commander sends his daughter for safety to the edge of the desert, and when he dies in battle she takes refuge with a desert tribe, who prove to have uncanny powers.
I believe the city under siege occurs in volume 3, Forging of the Sword.
